# Detecting when another application's caption changes

Tags: delphi

As the title states, I am trying to detect when another application's caption changes and perform a specific action only if the caption is different than it was when last checked. I am not sure if it helps or not but this is the code I am using to grab the caption of the other application.

```
function GetWinCaption: string;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  Len: LongInt;
  Title: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  Handle := FindWindow('Classname_Goes_Here', nil);
  if Handle <> 0 then
  begin
    Len := GetWindowTextLength(Handle) + 1;
    SetLength(Title, Len);
    GetWindowText(Handle, PChar(Title), Len);
    GetWinCaption := TrimRight(Title);
  end;
end;
```

The above code works fine to grab the caption, but I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around the code I would need to write to actually perform the check to see if the caption has changed or not.

This is the code I have been playing around with to do the check but I am not sure this is the best way to go about doing this and could use the advise of someone with more experience in this area.

```
var
 CurrCaption, PrevCaption : string;
...
...

if (CurrCaption = '') or (CurrCaption = PrevCaption) then
  begin
    CurrCaption := GetWinCaption;
  end
else
  begin
    PrevCaption := CurrCaption ;
  end;

// and then later on I do the comparison like this. 

if CurrCaption = PrevCaption then
  begin
    ShowMessage('not changed');
  end
else
  begin
    ShowMessage('changed');
  end;
```

Comment: You must backup the `CurrCaption` to `PrevCaption` before you get the new value. `PrevCaption := CurrCaption; CurrCaption := GetWinCaption;`. That's all, because you always need to get a current window caption and thus also always backup the last value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried adding `PrevCaption := CurrCaption` before `CurrCaption := GetWinCaption` in the code above, leaving everything else exactly the same, but when I ran a test the first time the caption changed it reported the change, but the 2nd time the caption changed it reported that they were the same meaning it failed somewhere. Maybe a small code snippet would help me find out where I need to adjust my code. Also, as I said is this really the only way to do this sort of check or should I look for another method.

Comment: [`Here it is`](http://pastebin.com/FUmwjJvQ).

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to write the snippet of code, but the part of the code that seems to have the problem is not in the checking code but rather in the code that is used to store the captions which is where I thought you said I needed to make the change in my original code.

Comment: Nvm, I tried using the single global variable version and it seems to be behave as expected. Much appreciated. If you want add your code from Pastebin as an answer to this question then I will accept and upvote it.